# OpenAM plugin for Apache reverse-proxy fails after sometime

Tags: apache, openam

We have OpenAM plugin for Apache Http server.
Here Apache Http server works as reverse-proxy.
OpenAM plugin validates user requests for authentication and authorisation then forwards the requests to service.
This works fine for some days.  But suddenly, OpenAM plugin fails to authenticate and authorise and requests directly goes to service.
Only fix is to restart the Apache HTTP server.

But this is not the correct fix. We would like to find the real route cause of this problem and fix. There is no logging reported from http server.

Thanks.

Comment: Which version of the OpenAM Web Agent for Apache http server is being used?

Comment: apache24_agent_v4.1.1 --> agent , 
openam-13.5.0 --> server

Comment: As there are quite a few forks from the ForgeRock source, where did you get this version from?

Comment: This is 1-2 year old installation.  I am not sure from where.

Comment: If you don't know where the source came from it will be hard or even impossible to find out what causes this behavior. Normally when the agent has some issue, you normally get a '403' HTTP response. You may run the agent in 'full message' logging potentially this tells if the request is even handed to the agent module by Apache http server 'runtime'.

Comment: There is no logs reported.  Totally clueless..  It is happening once in two days or so.

Answer (score 0):

> There is no logs reported. Totally clueless. It is happening once in two days or >so.

You should set the Agent level to message and check the debug.log (in agent root --> instances --> debu --> debug.log) and trace the requests in the agent log files that are not working. There may also be relevant information in the system logs in the agent root log folders.

> But suddenly, OpenAM plugin fails to authenticate and authorise and requests 
>   directly goes to service.

What HTTP status code is returned during this period? By default, if the Agent cannot communicate to AM for policy advice (unless it has preconfigured fallback not enforced URLs) will be to 403 each request. You'd really need to check your debug and apache access logs to look at these requests hitting the reverse proxy (or whether they hit them at all).